# High Capacity Phone Batteries - are they for real or a scam?

Tags: power, batteries, capacity

I recently bought a new, allegedly high capacity battery for my Samsung Galaxy S5. It was being sold as a 3800mAh battery whereas original is a 2800mAh battery.
On inspection I read the following from the cases of the 2 batteries;

Original Samsung:-          2800mAh, 3.85V, 10.78Wh

High capacity replacement:- 3800mAh, 3.85V, 10.78Wh

If Watts = Amps x Volts    then...   Watt-hrs = Amp-hrs x Volts

Therefore   Amp-hrs = Watt-hrs / Volts  or 10.78 / 3.85 = 2.8Ah (2800mAh)

This equates to 2800mAh  (2.8Ah) for both batteries so the replacement is wrongly labelled and sold as a 3800mAh Higher Capacity battery to Samsung Galaxy users.

Or have I got something wrong here?

Comment: It is not plausible that some no-name third party is going to fit a larger battery in the same form factor as Samsung. Also, the contradictory labeling is suspicious. My guess is that the 3.8Ah battery will have even less capacity than the original.

Comment: @mkeith Exactly - in case people have been avoiding the news for the last 6 months, Samsung is already building batteries that are right at the limit of what you can get away with in terms of density before they start to catch fire because of internal shorts...

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The alleged higher capacity battery is powering my phone for more or less the same amount of time.

Comment: @WillDean Actually, it seems they even *exceeded* this limit, with the Note 7.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The true measure of a battery's capacity is Wh. As you noted, the information on the new battery is contradictory. Either the Ah is wrong and it is higher capacity or the Wh is wrong and it is the same capacity.

The easiest way to tell is to try the new battery. 25% increase in capacity should be pretty easy to tell over a few days.

Comment: thank you for a quick response. I have tried the battery and it does NOT appear to last any longer than the 3 year old original battery.

Answer (score 2):

Fantasy capacities are quite popular.  You have already found that the new battery does not last longer than the old one.  You'll find out half a year down the road that it will last a whole lot *less* than the old one: the fantasy batteries tend to invest quite a lot less into the materials making a lithium ion accumulator actually long-lived (its chemistry is rather brutally corrosive and so needs a lot of mollycoddling at the cost of price and capacity).

So given today's market, you are likely better off looking for a battery of the original capacity or less.  That makes it more likely you'll get a battery that started out with significant life time expectations.  The only problem is that you might get 10-year old stock.

Answer (score 0):

I think they play on flexibility of electro-chemistry of the batteries. From my limited experience with Li-Ion batteries, the charge voltage level is not something of hard bounded. Many actual battery specifications (for  phone/tablets under development, usually not available to public, only to developers) list the charging voltage at 4.200 and even 4.300V. The charge can be done at slightly higher voltages resulting in [substantially higher amount of stored energy,](http://www.powerstream.com/lithium-ion-charge-voltage.htm) but at the expense of battery lifetime. So it is very possible that the manufacturer can really demonstrate the claim by using a special overcharging, but they wouldn't mention the resulting reduction in lifetime.

Since your phone is not aware of the "new" charging requirements, it would continue to charge it to old voltage, and therefore the perceived capacity will remain the same.